# How do I access the current index of d3 range

Tags: d3.js

how do I access the current index of a range ?

I found 
d3.range(data.length) returns [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

how do I access each value separately at each step?

Comment: What do you mean by "step"? `d3.range()` gives you an array of values, there are no steps or current indices.

Comment: I want to get 0 then 1 then 2 then 3 and so on at each step, I want to access data from another array at each step: differentArray[0], differentArray[1], ...

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the values? `d3.range(data.length).forEach(function(i) { ... });`

Comment: Or simply `differentArray.each(function(d) { ... })`.

Comment: thank you, not sure if it's what I want... (I'm starting to learn this). I would need to console.log (eachstep), then I would get 0, 1, 2, ... till the total number of steps, each output on its own line of console.log

Comment: What do you mean by "step"?

Comment: Post some code for your attempted project. A general rule of thumb in D3.js is to avoid for loops, unless you are crosstabulating.

Comment: I gave up on what I wanted to do, and started from scratch...reading and watching some tutorials on how d3 works.

Comment: I got it, well Lars Kotthoff told me, but I didn't get it then. function(d,i){...